# Reference request: $\int \Gamma(t)~dt$, the integral of the Euler's gamma function.

Tags: integration, reference-request, gamma-function

I cannot find *anything* discussing
$$\int \Gamma(t)~dt$$
As a definite or indefinite integral. Here, $\Gamma(x)$ is Euler's gamma function. I am looking for references which discuss the above integral and (hopefully) its properties$-$books, articles, anything.

---

Note: I am not looking for references on 
$$\int \log \Gamma(t)~dt.$$

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2155400/272831).

Comment: You can find interesting information and exercises in the Calculus Spivak, pag 394

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the integral of the gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2155400/what-is-the-integral-of-the-gamma-function)